# TypeError: start() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

Tags: python, pyqt

I want run some timer in thread，but it display ERROR`TypeError: start() argument after * must be an iterable, not int`，How can I fix it?

```
    while 1:
            try:
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.timer0.start,100)
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.timer1.start,150)
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.timer2.start,200)
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.timer3.start,250)
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.timer4.start,300)
                break
            except:
                print ("Error: unable to start thread")
            break
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html

> _thread.start_new_thread(function, args[, kwargs])
>
> Start a new thread and return its identifier. The thread executes the function function with the argument list args (which must be a tuple).

Thus, the correct call looks like:

```
_thread.start_new_thread(self.timer0.start, (100,))
```

Comment: It say 'QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread'

Comment: It seems that you are obsessed with threading, and you want to use it at all times, the QTimer is a QObject that is not thread-safe so you can not modify it from another thread, that's why Qt tells you not to modify the QTimer from a thread different from the what was created